# Achieve parallax effect in libGDX game

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm working in a game with some friends in which we have a large horizontal world and a [OrthographicCamera](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Orthographic-camera) that shows only 1/3 of it. This camera it's moved when the horizontal position of the player change so the camera only move to the left and to the right.

Some of the objects showed in the game are near the player point-of-view but others are far away (for example, islands). With this in consideration, we cannot set fixed positions for elements and move only the camera. We need to achieve a parallax effect taking in consideration the distance of the elements.

Here is a simple image to explain it better:
[image]
The viewport to the left shows 3 objects of the game. The green one is near the player, the red ellipse is far and the yellow one is in the middle. In the viewport to the right the camera has been moved to the right so all the objects disappear to the left. The thing is that the relative movement of the green rectangle is greater than the movement of the yellow. In the same way, movement of yellow object is greater than red object movement.

I created all my assets scaled taking in consideration how far they are but now, how can I simulate this perspective using libGDX? Is there any class to do it? If I have to set elements position in each iteration, how could I calculate the right position?

Comment: I would use a distinct OrthographicCamera for each layer. Think of each layer as having its own coordinate system scale. One of the layers would be your main layer where the game's physics takes place. On each frame, after updating the camera of your main layer, grab it's position and apply a scaled version of it as the position of each of your other layers' cameras' positions (each layer should have a camera position scale parameter). For each layer, first apply its camera's combined matrix to the sprite batch's projection matrix before adding that layer's sprites.

Comment: Here's an example. They did it using a single instance of a subclass of an OrthographicCamera, but it's the same basic concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that the example below is not tested as I am just recalling how I did it. The idea is simple - create layers with an extra layer for each with initial positions and velocity and move them. If a layer goes off the edge, put another one (that is why we create an extra layer) at the opposite edge.

Say you have a parallax object that takes initial positions, size, and velocity-

```
public class Parallax extends DynamicGameObject {

    public float width, height; // Use setter/getter if you prefer

    public Parallax(float x, float y, float width, float height, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        super(x, y, width, height);
        velocity.set(velocityX, velocityY);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

    }

    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        position.add(velocity.x * deltaTime, velocity.y * deltaTime);
    }

    public void setPosition(float x, float y) {
        position.set(x, y);
    }
}
```

DynamicGameObject is taken from [SuperJumper](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx-demo-superjumper) demo-

```
public class DynamicGameObject extends GameObject {

    public final Vector2 velocity;
    public final Vector2 accel;

    public DynamicGameObject(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        velocity = new Vector2();
        accel = new Vector2();
    }
}
```

GameObject as well-

```
public class GameObject {

    public final Vector2 position;
    public final Rectangle bounds;

    public GameObject(float x, float y, float width, float height) {
        this.position = new Vector2(x,y);
        this.bounds = new Rectangle(x - width/2f, y - height/2f, width, height);
    }
}
```

Say we have two layers - one in front and the other goes at back. We have one texture for each. Each texture fills the entire screen. We create two instances for each layer so that when one texture starts going off the screen, the other shows up at the edge to fill the gap. If you have smaller textures, you need to determine first how many textures you need to fill the screen and then create layers with one extra to fill the gap in between.

We can create an array of parallax layers during world creation-

```
Array<Parallax> parallaxList = new Array<Parallax>(4);
```

We can create the layers like this-

```
// Back
/* First parallax for back layer is at 0 x-axis. If you want to move the texture from right to left, the value of BACK_VELOCITY_X should be negative. You can experiment with velocity value for desire pace of movement. We do not want our layer to move on y-axis. Hence, it is set to 0. */

parallaxList.add(new Parallax(0, BACK_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, BACK_TEXTURE_WIDTH, BACK_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, BACK_VELOCITY_X, 0));

/* This one is also for back layer but it is positioned at the right edge of the layer above*/
parallaxList.add(new Parallax(BACK_TEXTURE_WIDTH, BACK_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, BACK_TEXTURE_WIDTH, BACK_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, SOME_VELOCITY_X, 0));

// Front
parallaxList.add(new Parallax(0, 0, FRONT_TEXTURE_WIDTH, FRONT_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, FRONT_VELOCITY_X, 0));
parallaxList.add(new Parallax(FRONT_TEXTURE_WIDTH, 0, FRONT_TEXTURE_WIDTH, FRONT_TEXTURE_HEIGHT, FRONT_VELOCITY_X, 0));
```

We update the layers on an update call in each frame-

```
// In our example, TOTAL_LAYERS is 4
for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_LAYERS; i++) {

    int tmpInt;
    Parallax parallax = parallaxList.get(i);

    parallax.update(deltaTime);

    // If one layer is off the edge, put it at the right of the next one
    // In this example, layers are moving from right to left
    if (parallax.position.x <= -parallax.width) {

        // We know that parallaxList's indexes 0 and 1 hold the back layers
        // and indexes 2 and 3 have the front layers. You can add additional
        // parameters in Parallax class to indicate a group so that you do not
        // have to determine the group in dirty way like this
        if(i == 0){
            tmpInt = 1;
        } else if(i == 1) {
            tmpInt = 0;
        } else if(i == 2) {
            tmpInt = 3;
        } else {
            tmpInt = 2;
        }

        parallax.setPosition(parallaxList.get(tmpInt).position.x + parallax.width, parallax.position.y);            
    }        
}
```

You can use an OrthographicCamera and a SpriteBatch to draw the parallax layers. You can actually use the game camera you have but I think using a separate camera is much cleaner. Anyways, parallax textures are usually big enough to be batched in a separate call so using the game camera most probably will not save you a draw call.